# How to get only some files to the Eclipse 'Package Explorer' tree (for Scala)

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, scala-ide

I find the "Package Explorer" or "Project Explorer" (are they the same?) in Eclipse Juno weird. In IDEs s.a. Visual Studio and XCode, I can select which files are "in the project" and thus shown in the IDE tree view. With Eclipse Juno, I get *all* the files and folders up there, and many of them are irrelevant.

Here's a picture.

I only want the files within `src`, `src/math` and `lib` to be listed. Specifically, these should go: `Makefile`, `Installing...rtf`, `build.sbt`, `test`, `target`, `project`, `bin`, `_Unused_`.

I was expecting there to be an option 'remove from project' (by right click) but all I get is the chance to really delete the file/folder. What's going on here? Or is it just that myself and Eclipse are not compatible? :)

[image: screenshot of project tree]

**Addendum:**

For me, the real reason not to use Eclipse became this:

*Before you begin, make sure your Scala sources follow the Java convention for packages. Each package should appear in its own directory with the same name. Eclipse expects this convention to be followed when it looks for classes.*

http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/gettingstarted.html

I don't want that. Scala does not enforce that. Bye-bye Eclipse, see you again in 10 years - maybe (last time I checked you was in 2004).

Comment: Eclipse Juno Service Release 1 64-bit for OS X, Scala IDE plugin 2.1.0-nightly

Answer (score 3):

You can use filters to hide these files from the project (they will still exist in the project):

1. Right click on the project, choose "Properties"
2. Choose Resource/Resource Filters
3. "Add..." a filter
4. Choose f.ex. "Exclude all", "Folders", "Name matches "target" etc.

(I never use this because I still find it useful to see all the files of a project.)

Comment: I think the IntelliJ IDEA has a better approach to this. It allows one to tag any files as 'source', 'test' or 'ignore', which at least suits my want perfectly. 1:0 for IntelliJ on this (and many other points as well)